# How can I tell if I am using the gstreamer codecs?

Tags: codecs, gstreamer

I installed the gstremer fluendo codecs. How do I know if I am  using them or how do I specify them as an argument for vlc or mplayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLC and MPlayer both use FFmpeg (+ some other) codecs to play media, but not the gstreamer ones (like fluendo-mp3). It is my understanding that this can't be changed by arguments or configuration, as it has not been implemented.

To be sure that you're using, say, fluendo mp3 decoder (flump3dec), use a command line similar to this:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=file.mp3 ! flump3dec ! audioconvert ! pulsesink
```

Other software may provide a way to inspect which gstreamer elements it is using for media operations.

(To add to the confusion, it is also possible to use FFmpeg through gstreamer, but it is *not* what you want.)